# Uniform position theorem for reducible varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The uniform position theorem states (roughly) that a general hyperplane section meets an irreducible degree $d$ curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ at $d$ points with any $r$ of them being independent (e.g. see general/uniform position theorems around section III.1 in vol. I of "Geometry of Algebraic Curves").

Is there a version of this when we remove the "irreducible" condition? For example, what happens if we consider points coming from some collection of disjoint irreducible curves? This seems plausible for many cases, but I'm not sure how to put this into a coherent statement and irreducibility seems to be an important part of proving this theorem.

Answer (score 2):

If a reducible curve is for you still a variety, then it is still quasi-compact, meaning it is a finite union of irreducible curves. So applying the theorem to each of the $k$ components, it follows that a generic hyperplane section meets a reducible curve in $\sum_{i=1}^k d_i$ points, where $d_i$ is the degree of each component.

I don't see any way to do better than this. This is exactly what you expect because a curve which is a union of two curves has as its defining equation the product of the equations of the irreducible components. Degree is additive, so this is just the same expression you'd get, except now we are paying attention to the components.

Comment: I do not think the OP was asking to do `better' than Bezout, since it is clearly impossible. The question is whether these points are in general position, if the hyperplane section is general. This is a more subtle issue.

Comment: Ah. Well then clearly you need some conditions. If for example, your curve is just the union of two lines, they will never be in general position. The question seems to have more to do with whether or not your reducible curve has automorphisms, such as interchanging some components with each other.

Comment: I do not see why two disjoint lines pose a problem.

Comment: Two disjoint lines are not a problem, but you could take a bunch of lines through a fixed point such that their points of intersection with the hyperplane all lie on a single line. These are certainly not in general position.

Comment: @TabesBridges The OP specifically mentions disjoint curves.

Comment: OK, take a bunch of disjoint lines which meet a fixed hyperplane along collinear points; the same idea works, no?

Comment: Do you think these kinds of constructions give the only possible concrete counterexamples? Also, is this something that works for a generic choice of a hyperplane?

Comment: @TabesBridges If you just take general lines through collinear points, then they nonuniformly meet that fixed hyperplane (or most hyperplanes containing the collinear points). But they will presumably still uniformly meet *general* hyperplanes.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Ahh, good point; I guess I was for some reason thinking about the as-nice-as-can-be situation of rational normal curves where *every* hyperplane section is in general position. OP, I suppose the worst situation my line of thinking can get you into would be to take a bunch of disjoint lines in a fixed $3$-plane. You won't get generally collinear points in your hyperplane section, but they will still be coplanar which is pretty far from general as long as $r$ is at least $5$ or $6$.

Comment: @TabesBridges OP has left out a truly crucial hypothesis which is that the irreducible curve must be non-degenerate (not lying in a hyperplane). I mean really, the OP states the theorem "roughly" but it's a simple statement: hypotheses **nondegenerate** irreducible curve, general hyperplane; conclusion, points in uniform position. ... For a reducible curve, you could get counterexamples like a (nondegenerate) union of a bunch of plane cubics (so any hyperplane section is a union of collinear triples of points).

Comment: ... To make it concrete, let's say, what if we require each component to be nondegenerate? This is not necessary for the uniformity property (a bunch of general lines has the uniformity property, but the lines are not each nondegenerate). Could it be sufficient? I think not, but I don't know. Say there are two components of degree $a,b$ ($a+b=d$). In the intersection, any $r$ of the first $a$ points are independent, as are any $r$ of the last $b$, but why would we expect independence of $r$ points involving some $a$'s and some $b$'s?